# Is it required to shard a MongoDB cluster to make it available worldwide?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, latency

Our entire database replica set is located in Europe.

We started getting some Asian clients and they are complaining about slowness when using our web application. We've deployed a set of app servers in Asia but they are still complaining about performance - so we realized the problem could be related to the databases being in Europe.

We've ran some tests using a single replica in asia, the reads were fast but the writes were still very slow.

It's impossible to make a master-master replication with MongoDB, so we're looking to shard our database.

But is this the only way to make the database fully available in different regions?

Cheers

Comment: If you don't need the database in Europe to talk to the one in Asia, I would rather create a separate deployment instead. It is possible to create a globe-spanning sharded cluster using e.g. [Zone Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/), but you must be prepared with the additional planning and operational complexity this solution will bring.

Comment: Thanks, @KevinAdistambha! We actually need it to communicate, our support team needs to troubleshoot issues that are related to Asian clients. In this case, would they still experience high latency?

Comment: I think we're talking about two different things. What I meant was, is there any dependency on Asia's data on Europe's data or vice versa, e.g. a centralized client ID or similar. Can you separate Asia's client IDs from Europe's client IDs cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (most probably)
Here is the link to support this thought: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#advantages-of-sharding

I didn't find any other solution in official documentation regarding your use case.